# Resetting a form with jquery is causing an unexpected syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to add a button that can clear a search input when clicked.

```js
$('.reset-form').click(function({
      $('#input-search').val('');
    });
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="search" required id="input-search" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="reset" class="reset-form" value="X">
  </form>
</div>
```

It is resulting in `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` on the 2nd line of js that is attempting to set a value on the search input text. I couldn't see anything wrong in a linter and was hoping for some guidance for why this error might be coming up.

Edit: corrected from `.value = '';` to `.val('');` and still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: It should be `$('#input-search').val('');` as `$('#input-search')` represents a jQuery object and not a DOM-node

Comment: @empiric thanks! I tried that and I'm getting the same error. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: It's not `.value('')` but `.val('')`

Comment: You have an extra `(`. `function({` should be `function {`

Comment: Using `type="reset"` should automatically clear any fields in the form. Is there a reason you're using JavaScript to do the same thing?

Comment: @JasonP It seems I was missing a ) instead of having an extra (. That got me fixed up though. :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It was because I wasn't seeing the search results that were being populated clear out like they were on a key escape (another part of the javascript not shown here). I do see what you mean though now that the script is fixed.

Comment: Oh, duh. Right.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That got me on the right track and got me fixing the real problem/issue I was having. Feel free to add an answer to that effect if you'd like the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. One is the syntax of your event handler. The [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function takes a function as an argument. So do that:

```js
$('.reset-form').click(function() {
    $('#input-search').val('');
});
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="search" required id="input-search" placeholder="Search">
    <input type="reset" class="reset-form" value="X">
  </form>
</div>
```

However, that just solves your syntax error.

The real question you should ask yourself is, "do I need this event handler at all?" The `type="reset"` you've applied to your second `input` should automatically clear any form elements inside the same form. So, in this case, it should clear the text field with an id of `input-search`. Whether that works with any other scripts you may have is a different question...

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
$('.reset-form').click(function({
    $('#input-search').val('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and I am still seeing the same error :/

Comment: When you view this in a browser, make sure you either clear the cache first or hit CTRL-F5 to refresh.  The browser may be still executing your old code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using middleman to run locally so all changes are reflected once they've been made.

Comment: I figured out it should be `$('.reset-form').click(function() {` I had a ) that was missing.